# remove array by matching two array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

remove array by matching two array. One is simple array and other is multidimensional array. I want to remove elements of second array if value not exist in 1st array. So there are total 20 element in 1st array. So there will be only 20 element in second array.

Final result that I want, where value should be match with Ist array. no element in second array whose value does not match in 1st array. So only the elements of second array whose value match with 1st array.

```
           Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => Afrikaans
        [value] => af
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => Albanian
        [value] => sq
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => Arabic
        [value] => ar
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => Armenian
        [value] => hy
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => Azerbaijani
        [value] => az
    )

 [5] => Array
    (
        [label] => Basque
        [value] => eu
     )

 [6] => Array
    (
        [label] => Belarusian
        [value] => be
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bengali
        [value] => bn
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bosnian
        [value] => bs
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bulgarian
        [value] => bg
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [label] => Catalan
        [value] => ca
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [label] => Cebuano
        [value] => ceb
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [label] => Chinese
        [value] => zh-CN
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [label] => Chinese (Traditional)
        [value] => zh-TW
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [label] => Croatian
        [value] => hr
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [label] => Czech
        [value] => cs
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [label] => Danish
        [value] => da
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [label] => Dutch
        [value] => nl
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [label] => English
        [value] => en
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [label] => Esperanto
        [value] => eo
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [label] => Estonian
        [value] => et
    )
```

**1st array**

```
      Array
(
[0] => ar
[1] => bn
[2] => zh-CN
[3] => en
[4] => fr
[5] => de
[6] => el
[7] => gu
[8] => hi
[9] => it
[10] => ja
[11] => kn
[12] => ko
[13] => la
[14] => mr
[15] => pa
[16] => ru
[17] => es
[18] => ta
[19] => te
[20] => ur
)
```

**2nd array**

```
   Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => Afrikaans
        [value] => af
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => Albanian
        [value] => sq
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => Arabic
        [value] => ar
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => Armenian
        [value] => hy
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => Azerbaijani
        [value] => az
    )

 [5] => Array
    (
        [label] => Basque
        [value] => eu
     )

 [6] => Array
    (
        [label] => Belarusian
        [value] => be
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bengali
        [value] => bn
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bosnian
        [value] => bs
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [label] => Bulgarian
        [value] => bg
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [label] => Catalan
        [value] => ca
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [label] => Cebuano
        [value] => ceb
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [label] => Chinese
        [value] => zh-CN
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [label] => Chinese (Traditional)
        [value] => zh-TW
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [label] => Croatian
        [value] => hr
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [label] => Czech
        [value] => cs
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [label] => Danish
        [value] => da
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [label] => Dutch
        [value] => nl
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [label] => English
        [value] => en
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [label] => Esperanto
        [value] => eo
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [label] => Estonian
        [value] => et
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [label] => Filipino
        [value] => tl
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [label] => Finnish
        [value] => fi
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [label] => French
        [value] => fr
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [label] => Galician
        [value] => gl
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [label] => Georgian
        [value] => ka
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [label] => German
        [value] => de
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [label] => Greek
        [value] => el
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [label] => Gujarati
        [value] => gu
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [label] => Haitian
        [value] => ht
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [label] => Hausa
        [value] => ha
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [label] => Hebrew
        [value] => iw
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [label] => Hindi
        [value] => hi
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [label] => Hmong
        [value] => hmn
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [label] => Hungarian
        [value] => hu
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [label] => Icelandic
        [value] => is
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [label] => Igbo
        [value] => ig
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [label] => Indonesian
        [value] => id
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [label] => Irish
        [value] => ga
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [label] => Italian
        [value] => it
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [label] => Japanese
        [value] => ja
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [label] => Javanese
        [value] => jv
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [label] => Kannada
        [value] => kn
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [label] => Khmer
        [value] => km
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [label] => Korean
        [value] => ko
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [label] => Lao
        [value] => lo
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [label] => Latin
        [value] => la
    )

[47] => Array
    (
        [label] => Latvian
        [value] => lv
    )

[48] => Array
    (
        [label] => Lithuanian
        [value] => lt
    )

[49] => Array
    (
        [label] => Macedonian
        [value] => mk
    )

[50] => Array
    (
        [label] => Malay
        [value] => ms
    )

[51] => Array
    (
        [label] => Maltese
        [value] => mt
    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [label] => Maori
        [value] => mi
    )

[53] => Array
    (
        [label] => Marathi
        [value] => mr
    )

[54] => Array
    (
        [label] => Norwegian
        [value] => no
    )

[55] => Array
    (
        [label] => Persian
        [value] => fa
    )

[56] => Array
    (
        [label] => Polish
        [value] => pl
    )

[57] => Array
    (
        [label] => Portuguese
        [value] => pt
    )

[58] => Array
    (
        [label] => Punjabi
        [value] => pa
    )

[59] => Array
    (
        [label] => Romanian
        [value] => ro
    )

[60] => Array
    (
        [label] => Russian
        [value] => ru
    )

[61] => Array
    (
        [label] => Serbian
        [value] => sr
    )

[62] => Array
    (
        [label] => Slovak
        [value] => sk
    )

[63] => Array
    (
        [label] => Slovenian
        [value] => sl
    )

[64] => Array
    (
        [label] => Somali
        [value] => so
    )

[65] => Array
    (
        [label] => Spanish
        [value] => es
    )

[66] => Array
    (
        [label] => Swahili
        [value] => sw
    )

[67] => Array
    (
        [label] => Swedish
        [value] => sv
    )

[68] => Array
    (
        [label] => Tamil
        [value] => ta
    )

[69] => Array
    (
        [label] => Telugu
        [value] => te
    )

[70] => Array
    (
        [label] => Thai
        [value] => th
    )

[71] => Array
    (
        [label] => Turkish
        [value] => tr
    )

[72] => Array
    (
        [label] => Ukrainian
        [value] => uk
    )

[73] => Array
    (
        [label] => Urdu
        [value] => ur
    )

[74] => Array
    (
        [label] => Vietnamese
        [value] => vi
    )

[75] => Array
    (
        [label] => Welsh
        [value] => cy
    )

[76] => Array
    (
        [label] => Yiddish
        [value] => yi
    )

[77] => Array
    (
        [label] => Yoruba
        [value] => yo
    )

[78] => Array
    (
        [label] => Zulu
        [value] => zu
    )

  )
```

[Example](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3039633/c9f5481aa68cb839321d84cf13e658e3)

Comment: What did you tried, can you share?

Comment: To clarify: the array at the very bottom, with 79 entries, is your input data, and you want to use the one-dimensional array in the middle to filter this, and the first array in your question is the expected output? But it seems the entries of the first and second array of your question, i.e. filter and result array, do not match, e.g. "af" is in the first and third, but not second array.

Comment: I have added the link for example

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = your first array;
$a2 = second array;

foreach($a2 as $k => $v)
{
    if(!in_array($v['value'],$a1)
    {
        unset($a2[$k]);
    }
}
```

So you will have $a2 with the only remaining values which will be present in `$a1`.

Comment: How to get final array ?

Comment: After the foreach look, if you will do `print_r($a2);` you will see that your $a2 is the desired array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to preserve the indexes in the second array, you can flip the first array and assign temporary keys to the second and call `array_intersect_key()`.

Though this appears to make several function calls, none of them are done in a loop.  Using `in_array()` inside of a loop, will mean (in your case) that php will be doing 59 full array scans and 20 partial scans -- This will not be efficient.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f86a1cd90dfbdf8d647884ef4debe652d477ec56))

```
var_export(  // print to screen
    array_values(  // this is optional.  This just reindexes the array
        array_intersect_key(  // retain elements where key exists in both arrays
            array_column($fulllist,null,'value'),  // make new keys for 2nd array
            array_flip($keep)  // swap values and indexes of 1st array
        )
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Arabic',
    'value' => 'ar',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Bengali',
    'value' => 'bn',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Chinese',
    'value' => 'zh-CN',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'English',
    'value' => 'en',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'French',
    'value' => 'fr',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'German',
    'value' => 'de',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Greek',
    'value' => 'el',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Gujarati',
    'value' => 'gu',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Hindi',
    'value' => 'hi',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Italian',
    'value' => 'it',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Japanese',
    'value' => 'ja',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Kannada',
    'value' => 'kn',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Korean',
    'value' => 'ko',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Latin',
    'value' => 'la',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Marathi',
    'value' => 'mr',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Punjabi',
    'value' => 'pa',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Russian',
    'value' => 'ru',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Spanish',
    'value' => 'es',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Tamil',
    'value' => 'ta',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Telugu',
    'value' => 'te',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Urdu',
    'value' => 'ur',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy (if i managed to understand...)

```
let newArray = languages.filter(lang => return codes.indexof(lang.value) !== -1);
```

**UPDATE**

Oh my :-) wrong language, sorry

```
$final = array_filter($languages, function($language) use($codes) { return in_array($language['value'], $codes)});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Lets brake it down:

array_filter can be used to filter an array :-), by default array_filter will remove "falsy" values. With a callback as second parameter you can define how to filter the input array. The first parameter is the input array.

I use array_filter instead of unsetting the original values, because its cleaner and more robust.

PHP knows anonymous functions - a filter operation is a perfect usecase for that. But because PHP is not the best programming language out there we have to use a special syntax to simulate some kind of scoping, thats why you see this part:

```
use($codes)
```

if i would define the filter like:

```
$final = array_filter($languages, function($language) {
    return in_array($language['value'], $codes)
});
```

PHP would throw an exception because $codes is not defined within the function scope.

Anonymous functions support the use() block, that way we can "expose" the codes-array to our function.

```
$final = array_filter($languages, function($language) use($codes) {
    return in_array($language['value'], $codes)
});
```

finally we check if the language is valid, by searching for the language-value inside our $codes array (which will hold the allowed languages). If the code does not exist in $codes in_array will return `false` and we return that to array_filter, so this element is not valid.

If the code of the checked language exists in codes, in_array will return true, we return it to array_filter and the item is valid.

Comment: Sorry, too much coding today... added php snippet. thank you